# Rcurl parsing HTML webpage using class tag

Tags: r, html-parsing, rcurl

I am trying to parse the following webpage to return the links of each result sub-page. However, the 'result' dimension just returns an empty list. What do i need to put into the span clause in order for it to correctly return the header and underlying URL of each result page?

Many thanks.

```
# load packages
library(RCulr)
library(XML)

# download html
url = "http://www.sportinglife.com/racing/results"
http = htmlParse(url)
result = lapply(http['//span[@class="hdr t2"]'],xmlValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy. When you look at "hdr t2" in the source code of the url you'll notice that the tag containing this as a class name is a h3 tag while you are querying for a span tag. Replace "span" with "h3" and it'll work. This works for me

```
     # load packages
     library(RCulr)
     library(XML)

     # download html
     url = "http://www.sportinglife.com/racing/results"
     http = htmlParse(url)
     result = lapply(http['//h3[@class="hdr t2"]'],xmlValue)
```

I say it's easy, but it's easy to oversee as well :)